# Adding multiple values at once to an 2d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I am a newbie at python I am trying to create simple program that assigns each letter of the alphabet in an 2d array with a random number. I have managed to do that but it looks very inefficient. I think a loop could be implemented into the code and reduce the amount of unnecessary code but I am unsure how to do that. any ideas? or help?

```
from array import *
import random

list2 = []
for i in range(100):
    r = random.randint(0,26)
    if r not in list2: list2.append(r) 
T2 = [["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
     ["_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_","_",]]


T2[1][0] = list2[0]
T2[1][1] = list2[1]
T2[1][2] = list2[2]
T2[1][3] = list2[3]
T2[1][4] = list2[4]
T2[1][5] = list2[5]
T2[1][6] = list2[6]
T2[1][7] = list2[7]
T2[1][8] = list2[8]
T2[1][9] = list2[9]
T2[1][10] = list2[10]
T2[1][11] = list2[11]
T2[1][12] = list2[12]
T2[1][13] = list2[13]
T2[1][14] = list2[14]
T2[1][15] = list2[15]
T2[1][16] = list2[16]
T2[1][17] = list2[17]
T2[1][18] = list2[18]
T2[1][19] = list2[19]
T2[1][20] = list2[20]
T2[1][21] = list2[21]
T2[1][22] = list2[22]
T2[1][23] = list2[23]
T2[1][24] = list2[24]
T2[1][25] = list2[25]



for r in T2:
    for c in r:
        print(c,end = " ")
    print()
```

Comment: What should happen if `list2` doesn't have at least 26 elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the alphabet from [string.ascii_uppercase](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) and then shuffle the numbers 0-25 to get a random order.

```
>>> import string
>>> import random
>>> res = [list(string.ascii_uppercase), sorted(range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)), key=lambda x:random.random())]
>>> res
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], [3, 12, 7, 8, 9, 14, 11, 24, 6, 18, 17, 1, 5, 15, 16, 13, 2, 19, 20, 25, 0, 21, 23, 4, 10, 22]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a slice of `list2` when initializing `T2`.

```
T2 = [["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
      list2[:26]]
```

And you can create `list2` without a loop:

```
list2 = list(range(26))
random.shuffle(list2)
```

Your loop isn't even guaranteed to create a list with at least 26 elements. Theoretically, `random.randint()` could return the same number every time, so all checks if the number is already in the list would fail after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string` module that contains all the English letters and the `random` module for shuffling your data. For example:

```py
import string
from random import shuffle


letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
indexes = list(range(len(letters)))
shuffle(indexes)

array_2d = list(zip(indexes, letters))
print(array_2d)

>>>
[['11' 'A']
 ['24' 'B']
 ['9' 'C']
 ['5' 'D']
 ['23' 'E']
 ['0' 'F']
 ['17' 'G']
 ['8' 'H']
 ['25' 'I']
 ['18' 'J']
 ['21' 'K']
 ['16' 'L']
 ['19' 'M']
 ['4' 'N']
 ['6' 'O']
 ['15' 'P']
 ['3' 'Q']
 ['13' 'R']
 ['10' 'S']
 ['7' 'T']
 ['20' 'U']
 ['12' 'V']
 ['1' 'W']
 ['22' 'X']
 ['2' 'Y']
 ['14' 'Z']]
```